# Identifying dependencies of R functions and scripts

Tags: r, dependencies, code-analysis

I am sifting through a package and scripts that utilize the package, and would like to identify external dependencies.  The goal is to modify scripts to specify `library(pkgName)` and to modify functions in the package to use `require(pkgName)`, so that these dependencies will be more obvious later.

I am revising the code to account for each externally dependent package.  As an example, though it is by no means definitive, I am now finding it difficult to identify code that depends on `data.table`.  I could replace `data.table` with `Matrix`, `ggplot2`, `bigmemory`, `plyr`, or many other packages, so feel free to answer with examples based on other packages.

This search isn't particularly easy.  The approaches I have tried so far include:

- Search the code for `library` and `require` statements
- Search for mentions of `data.table` (e.g. `library(data.table)`)
- Try running `codetools::checkUsage` to determine where there may be some issues.  For the scripts, my program inserts the script into a local function and applies `checkUsage` to that function.  Otherwise, I use `checkUsagePackage` for the package.
- Look for statements that are somewhat unique to `data.table`, such as `:=`.
- Look for where objects' classes may be identified via Hungarian notation, such as `DT`

The essence of my searching is to find:

- loading of `data.table`,
- objects with names that indicate they are `data.table` objects,
- methods that appear to be `data.table`-specific

The only easy part of this seems to be finding where the package is loaded.  Unfortunately, not all functions may explicitly load or require the external package - these may assume it has already been loaded.  This is a bad practice, and I am trying to fix it.  However, searching for objects and methods seems to be challenging.

This (`data.table`) is just one package, and one with what seems to be limited and somewhat unique usage.  Suppose I wanted to look for uses of ggplot functions, where the options are more extensive, and the text of the syntax is not as idiosyncratic (i.e. frequent usage of `+` is not idiosyncratic, while `:=` seems to be).

I don't think that static analysis will give a perfect answer, e.g. one could pass an argument to a function, which specifies a package to be loaded.  Nonetheless: are there any core tools or packages that can improve on this brute force approach, either via static or dynamic analysis?

For what it's worth, `tools::pkgDepends` only addresses dependencies at the package level, not the function or script level, which is the level I'm working at.

---

Update 1: An example of a dynamic analysis tool that should work is one that reports which packages are loaded during code execution.  I don't know if such a capability exists in R, though - it would be like `Rprof` reporting the output of `search()` instead of the code stack.

Comment: Could you try `foodweb` in package `mvbutils`? I don't have experience with it myself but it seems promising to me (except I don't know how deep it searches). Something like `foodweb(where='package:data.table',prune='function_youre_examining')`?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee That is very intriguing.  It looks like it would be quite useful intra-package; I'm not yet clear on what it can do inter-package, but I will give it a whirl, thanks!

Comment: @mathematical.coffee This is very interesting.  I am plugging away at it a bit further.  Can you post your comment as an answer?  I may help edit it into a solution, assuming I can get it to work.  I previously commented that it didn't seem to work across packages, but that's not correct.  The `where` argument seems to do the trick for managing the search space.  Btw, the help for changed.funs reads almost as I would write about some of my recent experiences. :)

Comment: Would be easy to do dynamically. Use trace to modify all functions in a package to record the function name and call stack.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and accept it - I know of `foodweb` but haven't used it myself, so you're the one who's done all the hard work! :)

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Finding-inter-function-dependencies-within-a-package-td3855218.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, thanks to @mathematical.coffee to putting me on the path of using Mark Bravington's `mvbutils` package.  The `foodweb` function is more than satisfactory.

To recap, I wanted to know about about checking one package, say `myPackage` versus another, say `externalPackage`, and about checking scripts against the `externalPackage`.  I'll demonstrate how to do each.  In this case, the external package is `data.table`.

1: For `myPackage` versus `data.table`, the following commands suffice:

```
library(mvbutils)
library(myPackage)
library(data.table)
ixWhere <- match(c("myPackage","data.table"), search())
foodweb(where = ixWhere, prune = ls("package:data.table"), descendents = FALSE)
```

This produces an excellent graph showing which functions depend on functions in `data.table`.  Although the graph includes dependencies within `data.table`, it's not overly burdensome: I can easily see which of my functions depend on `data.table`, and which functions they use, such as `as.data.table`, `data.table`, `:=`, `key`, and so on.  At this point, one could say the package dependency problem is solved, but `foodweb` offers so much more, so let's look at that.  The cool part is the dependency matrix.

```
depMat  <- foodweb(where = ixWhere, prune = ls("package:data.table"), descendents = FALSE, plotting = FALSE)
ix_sel  <- grep("^myPackage.",rownames(depMat))
depMat  <- depMat[ix_sel,]
depMat  <- depMat[,-ix_sel]
ix_drop <- which(colSums(depMat) == 0)
depMat  <- depMat[,-ix_drop]
ix_drop <- which(rowSums(depMat) == 0)
depMat  <- depMat[-ix_drop,]
```

This is cool: it now shows dependencies of functions in my package, where I'm using verbose names, e.g. `myPackage.cleanData`, on functions not
in my package, namely functions in `data.table`, and it eliminates rows and columns where there are no dependencies.  This is concise, lets me survey dependencies quickly, and I can find the complementary set for my functions quite easily, too, by processing `rownames(depMat)`.

NB: `plotting = FALSE` doesn't seem to prevent a plotting device from being created, at least the first time that `foodweb` is called in a sequence of calls.  That is annoying, but not terrible.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

2: For scripts versus `data.table`, this gets a little more interesting.  For each script, I need to create a temporary function, and then check for dependencies.  I have a little function below that does precisely that.

```
listFiles <- dir(pattern = "myScript*.r")
checkScriptDependencies <- function(fname){
    require(mvbutils)
    rawCode  <- readLines(fname)
    toParse  <- paste("localFunc <- function(){", paste(rawCode, sep = "\n", collapse = "\n"), "}", sep = "\n", collapse = "")
    newFunc  <- eval(parse(text = toParse))
    ix       <- match("data.table",search())
    vecPrune <- c("localFunc", ls("package:data.table"))
    tmpRes   <- foodweb(where = c(environment(),ix), prune = vecPrune, plotting = FALSE)
    tmpMat   <- tmpRes$funmat
    tmpVec   <- tmpMat["localFunc",]
    return(tmpVec)
}

listDeps <- list()
for(selFile in listFiles){
    listDeps[[selFile]] <- checkScriptDependencies(selFile)
}
```

Now, I just need to look at `listDeps`, and I have the same kind of wonderful little insights that I have from the depMat above.  I modified `checkScriptDependencies` from other code that I wrote that sends scripts to be analyzed by `codetools::checkUsage`; it's good to have a little function like this around for analyzing standalone code.  Kudos to [@Spacedman](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2307138#2307138) and [@Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773047/805808) for insights that improved the call to `foodweb`, using `environment()`.

(True hungaRians will notice that I was inconsistent with the order of name and type - tooBad.  :)  There's a longer reason for this, but this isn't precisely the code I'm using, anyway.)

---

Although I've not posted pictures of the graphs produced by `foodweb` for my code, you can see some nice examples at http://web.archive.org/web/20120413190726/http://www.sigmafield.org/2010/09/21/r-function-of-the-day-foodweb. In my case, its output definitely captures data.table's usage of `:=` and `J`, along with the standard named functions, like `key` and `as.data.table`.  It seems to obviate my text searches and is an improvement in several ways (e.g. finding functions that I'd overlooked).

All in all, `foodweb` is an excellent tool, and I encourage others to explore the `mvbutils` package and some of Mark Bravington's other nice packages, such as `debug`.  If you do install `mvbutils`, just check out `?changed.funs` if you think that only you struggle with managing evolving R code.  :)