# %between% function possible improvement

Tags: r, data.table

As per `data.table` ver 1.8.8 `%between%` is defined as follow:

```
> `%between%`
function (x, y) 
between(x, y[1], y[2], incbounds = TRUE)
<bytecode: 0x0000000050912810>
<environment: namespace:data.table>
```

I thought that, with this tiny change, this function would be vectorised,

```
function (x, y) 
    between(x, y[[1]], y[[2]], incbounds = TRUE)
```

like `between`

```
s <- c(2, 5)
d <- c(7, 9)
> between(3, s, d)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

The idea came from having a list with two vectors, which suggested me this possible usage:

```
`between2%` <- function(x, lst) between(x, lst[[1]], lst[[2]], incbounds = TRUE)

> 3%between%c(s,d)
[1] TRUE
> 3%between2%list(s,d)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

My question is: if I replaced `%between%` would any functionality in `data.table` package be affected? I think it shouldn't, `[[` should work with atomic vector as `[` does. Am I correct? thanks

```
> 3%between2%c(1,5)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: The answer is NO. You should be able to overwrite any function in any package and this should not affect the package.

Comment: @agstudy ok thanks, just wonder about any dependencies ( in terms of other functions calling this one) and about `[[` vs `[` with atomic vectors. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was an interesting question because I wondered how one might look, in general, for uses of a function by other functions. As far as I know, there's no way to directly do this (perhaps someone can correct me?). But, I put together a little code that looks for function names in text representations of other functions. For `%between%`, here's the following:

```
library(data.table)
objs <- objects("package:data.table")
z <- textConnection("funs", open="w")
dump(list=objs, file=z)
close(z)

# find all mentions of `%between%` in `data.table` functions
funs[grep("%between%",funs)] ## only mentions are when %between% is defined

# find all mentions of all `data.table` functions in `data.table` functions
locations <- lapply(objs, function(x) grep(x,funs))
names(locations) <- objs
```

*UPDATE*: After doing some more searching, [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761857/identifying-dependencies-of-r-functions-and-scripts) also seem to provide some more information on how to detect dependencies programmatically using `foodweb` from `library(mvbutils)`.

Comment: thanks a lot! very helpful. I also found a strange behavior. My R session crashes as soon as `R` gets this line `dump(list=objs, file=z)`. In my workspace there are several tens of `data.frame` and `data.table`, the .RData is almost 1 GB and occupies 10GB in the ram. But running your code in an empty workspace this does not happen. Anyway, thanks again

Comment: That's interesting...we need someone far more expert than I to figure that one out.

Comment: I think it would be difficult either. I can't reproduce this scenario, I would have raised a question :-). I tried with some dummy tables, but nothing. Btw, I just saw your `rite` package. very good. Could you tell me your ideas in regards of [this](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/4258-code-completion-inside-functions)

Comment: I've thought about incorporating something like that in `rite`. But first I want to build a better interface to the existing syntax highlighting, because I'd like people to be able to dynamically control it. Then doing the same for new objects and variables within dataframes would be relatively simple. I don't know how to do in rstudio, though.

Comment: Of course I meant in your package. If you do that I'll switch over!

Comment: Hi, why do you choose `objects("package:data.table")`? `objects(asNamespace("data.table"))` has much more names :-)

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft That's an alternative, I suppose...but if I understand it what I have calls only things exported by the package, which is theoretically all that any other package should use. `asNamespace` isn't well documented, though, so I can't really evaluate the trade-offs.