# Is there an easy way to tell if an R script made use of any function in a loaded package?

Tags: r

For example, if ran the `script.A`:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 a <- 12
```

and then `script.B`

```
library(ggplot2)
b <- runif(100)
qplot(b)
```

I'd be able to tell that `script.A` did not actually make use of `ggplot2`, whereas `script.B` did.

Comment: Do you need to know what package the functions came from?

Comment: What I'd actually like to do is eliminate packages that are not being used. As I re-use code from old projects, I seem to always add (but never take-away) packages, and while I could manually do some kind of bisect to find the unused packages, this would be a hassle. Ideally, I could just get a post-execution run-down of what actually was called.

Comment: Do any of these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761857/identifying-dependencies-of-r-functions-and-scripts and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402735/between-function-possible-improvement

Answer (score 5):

Load the library normally and trace all functions in the package environment (and in the namespace). I'll use a small helper function to do this:

```
trap_funs <- function(env)
{
    f <- sapply(as.list(env, all.names=TRUE), is.function)
    for( n in names(f)[f] ) trace(n, bquote(stop(paste("Script called function", .(n)))), where=env)
}
```

Example:

```
library(data.table)
trap_funs(as.environment("package:data.table"))
trap_funs(asNamespace("data.table"))
```

This second statement is needed to ensure that calls such as `data.table::xxx()` also get trapped.

Example:

```
> as.data.table(mtcars)
Tracing as.data.table(mtcars) on entry 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Script called function as.data.table
```

Note that the code was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) First issue a `library()` call for each package that you do *NOT* want to test for.  In this case there is only one package which is the one we wish to test for so we can skip this step.

2) Run the script with `library` dummied out:

```
library <- list
source("script.A")
rm(library) # restore
```

If you get no errors then the script does not depend on the package.

Comment: I'd put `base::library()` in my script :-)

Comment: What about namespace imports? You might not get an error because something was imported into another loaded package. Probably rare, but seems possible.