# Find unused functions in R

Tags: r, function

I have been working for a few months on a project, and there are now about 120 functions. About one third of these functions are no longer necessary to run the final version the script. The functions are all loaded from a function folder into a separate namespace.

Is there a way in R to see which functions are called?
The alternative is to go to the script and write down the functions that are now actually used.

Comment: I think Rprof would be a good start

Comment: How about loading your script file as a text (character) object into `R` and running a loop over all function names, doing `grepl` on each one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761857/identifying-dependencies-of-r-functions-and-scripts for ideas on how to see relationships between functions.

Comment: @baptiste - that sounds promising. When I run rprof ny functions are marked <Anonymous>.

Comment: Using Carl's method, you could get all of the function names from the local environment using: `as.character(lsf.str(".GlobalEnv"))`. Then use grepl on each one

Comment: @av1 - all my functions are loaded into a namespace FUN. I will try Carl's method, but it involves some programming time [for me].

Comment: @baptiste - it looks as if I get meaningful results [for my question] out of rprof only when i group all my functions into a R package, is that right?

Comment: @Henk I'm afraid I don't know, it was just a hint in passing. That being said, packages are very useful and trivial to make.

Comment: Is this one script with all functions?  Please provide a minimal reproducible example so we know what we're dealing with.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker - it is a collection of 5 scripts. There is, as explained in the question, a folder with the functions that is loaded in a separate environment. Making a reproducable example is in particular case a bigger operation than weeding out the redundant functions by hand.

Comment: @Henk I said **minimal** reproducible.  You could do this with 5 dummy functions in less than 3 minutes.  It you wanted to make it more realistic you could use `readLines` + `cat` to output to separate files.  `dir.create` would make the folder.  In 6 minutes you could have this as a reproducible problem that would benefit the community.  Right now you're getting hints as comments because folks don't wanna take the time to reproduce your problem.  Keep in mind R can run code not explanations of code.  Try the MWE and I bet a cup of coffee that within an hour you get an answer.