# R: graphical overview of functions in a package

Tags: r, function, graph, dependencies, package

Is there a way in R to get an overview of the relationship between functions? E.g. I am developing a package and would like a graph that shows which function calls which other functions (in the same package and / or externally). I suspect that this functionality is already available from an existing package, as I have seen it for several other programming languages, but I have been unable to find it in Google.

Comment: The first version of the roxygen package had something like this. you could look there (it has been archived on CRAN)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8777882/1412059